# how to configure set_error_handler in lithium

Tags: error-handling, lithium

I would like to understand how exception handling is working in Lithium

I want to add code to handle fatal error by using register_shutdown_function in lithium

It's quite easy in other framework but I am not getting the right way to do it in lithium framework.

http://li3.me/docs/manual/handling-http-requests/controllers.md I have gone through this link as well but not help.

Can someone help?

Comment: In ErroHanlder.php : @var boolean True if custom error/exception handlers have been registered, false otherwise, someone have any idea how to register custom error/exception handler ??? I want to define register_shutdown_function() in ErrorHandler.php..

Comment: I have added the register_shutdown_function in webroot/index.php. The code is working but don't know if it's a right way to do it.